# Rspec problems with namespaced controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am having trouble testing my a few controllers using Rspec, especially those that use namespaces in their routes. Does anyone have an idea for why this is happening and how I can correct it? It's driving me crazy.

Here is my error.
Failure/Error: get 'show'
ActionController::RoutingError:
No route matches {:controller=>"community/vendors", :action=>"show"}

Here is my controller.

```
class Community::VendorsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @vendor = Vendor.find_by_uuid(params[:uuid])
    render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html",  :status => 404 if @vendor.nil?
  end
end
```

Here is my spec.

```
describe Community::VendorsController do
  let(:vendor){FactoryGirl.create(:vendor)}
  before(:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:vendor_single_user)
    sign_in @user
  end

  it 'should return 404 if no vendor found' do
    Vendor.stub(:find_by_uuid => nil)
    get 'show'
    response[:status].should == 404
  end
end
```

Here are the routes.

```
  namespace :community do
    get  ':uuid/intake' => 'vendors#show'
    put ':uuid/intake/' => 'vendors#update'
    get ':uuid/check-email' => 'vendors#check_email'
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your route expects a `:uuid` parameter but in your spec you are not supplying that parameter.  Update your spec to pass in the `uuid` parameter:

```
describe Community::VendorsController do
  ...

  it 'should return 404 if no vendor found' do
    Vendor.stub(:find_by_uuid => nil)
    get 'show', uuid: uuid # Replace uuid with your object's uuid
    response[:status].should == 404
  end
end
```